# Trying to use parameters dynamically using powershell

Tags: powershell, dynamic, parameters

I am trying to setup dynamic parameters that vary depending on if you are adding or modifying/removing a drone. Ex: If you are adding a drone you would need its IP/Name/Location.. To remove the drone you would only need its name. I have tried looking online and try various examples I've seen but I am completely stuck here. Any help to steer me in the right direction would be appreciated. I am somewhat new to powershell. Here's what I have.

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
Param(  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage = "Add remove or Modify a drone?")]
        [ValidateSet("Add", "Remove", "Modify")]
        [String]$Action)


      DynamicParam{

        if ($action = "Add"){

            Param( [Parameter(Mandatory)]
            [ValidateSet("NorthAmerica", "SouthAmerica", "NorthernEurope","UK", "CEE", "FRMALU", "SouthernEurope", "AsiaPacific")]
            [String]$curRegion,
            [Parameter(Mandatory)]
            [IPAddress]$ip,
            [Parameter(Mandatory)]
            [String]$droneName)

        }
        if ($action = "Remove"){
            Param( 
                [Parameter(Mandatory)]
                [string]$droneRemoveName)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider driving your parameter constraints with named [Parameter Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-parameter-sets?view=powershell-6) instead. I'm suggesting this because dynamic parameters don't work quite like you think they do, but named parameter sets are an easier way to solve your problem. In case you're interested, [here's a blog post explaining](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/using-dynamic-parameters) how to use dynamic parameters and it winds up being pretty manual parameter handling.

You can add a parameter to more than one parameter set depending on the contexts in which each parameter is required. Instead of using `-Action ACTION` as a driver for a dynamic parameter, use a `[switch]` instead, such as `-Add` and `-Remove`, and have each switch part of its own parameter set. For example, when defining your parameters, it may look something like this:

```
Param(
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Remove')]
  [switch]$Remove,
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Add')]
  [switch]$Add,
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Remove', Mandatory)]
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Add', Mandatory)]
  [string]$IPAddress
)
```

In this example, `-IPAddress` is valid when you use the `-Add` or `-Remove` switch, but won't be relavant outside of this context. Of course, if a parameter should only be valid for a certain parameter set, don't define it under more than one parameter set name.

---

If you want to make sure at least one "action" switch is defined before executing, you can check that one of those parameters was used when invoking the cmdlet by checking `$PSBoundParameters`:

```
('Add' -in $PSBoundParameters.Keys) -Or ('Remove' -in $PSBoundParameters.Keys)
```